# Count how many letters in a name with input "A" in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

For Example: "Mahatma Gandhi" - how many A's are in the name ?
I need a query for this. any help pls !

Comment: which db you are really using ??

Answer (score 3):

REGEX could be used to get the count of a letter in a string

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('Mahatma Gandhi', 'a') FROM DUAL;
```

For case-insensitive search

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('Mahatma Gandhi',
                     'A',
                     1,
                     'i')
          REGEXP_COUNT
  FROM DUAL;
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014)

Comment: . . For case-insensitive, I would just use `'[aA]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using length and replace

```
select length( 'Mahatma Gandhi') -  length( replace('Mahatma Gandhi', 'a','')) num_char
from dual
```